# Spring: Cannot resolve method 'signInWithEmailAndPassword' in 'FirebaseAuth'

Tags: spring, firebase

I have a spring backend, but the users data are in a firebase project.
I want to create a login API. but I don't know how to check the password of the user is correct.

I try to use the "signInWithEmailAndPassword" but seems it only exist for android

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/gismat/spring-firebase-authentication